# Applying Max-Width to a Fixed-Positioned Div Within a Relative-Positioned Div?

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

What is the best way to align a fixed div within a relative div to the right, while still keeping an inherited `max-width`?

**Update (Jan 24, 2018):** I've answered this question with the solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48432249/9214076).

See the following snippet for further reference:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.max-width {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.box {
  max-width: inherit;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="max-width">
    <div class="box">fix to right?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured something out. It can be done after all!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

.box1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap-box {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 0;
}

.wrap-box > div.box2 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap-box > div.box3 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <div class="box1">position: relative, width: 20%</div>
  <div class="container">
    position: absolute, width: 60%
    <div class="wrap-box">
      <div class="box2">position: fixed (top), width: 20%</div>
      <div class="box3">position: fixed (bottom), width: 20%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

A fixed element's position is always relative to the viewport/window, never to any other element.

The only thing you can do (with CSS) is to use `right: calc(50% - 250px);` for its position to have it right aligned to the right border of the 500px wide centered "parent" element, but that will only work if the screen is wider or equal to the `max-width` of the "parent"  element.

Addition after comments: Plus add a media query for screens below 500px width with `right: 0` (thanks to @MrLister for that)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.max-width {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.box {
  max-width: inherit;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(50% - 250px);
  background: blue;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .box {
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="max-width">
    <div class="box">fix to right?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And a media query with `right:0` for narrower screens.

Comment: Well, I do like the result of your answer, but this only half solved the issue... Since I needed for the fixed-positioned div to remain 20% width inherent to the max-width div, since when I stretch the div beyond 500px max-width, the fixed div expands as well...

Comment: @nrweb You never mentioned that in the question. Anyway, the answer is the same: use a media query.

Comment: I developed a solution on my own, but thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

What if you did this:

Css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.max-width {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.box {
  max-width: inherit;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(50% - 250px);
  background: blue;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.box {
      right: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
.box {
      width: 100px; /* 100px is 20% of the max-width */
    }
}
```

Html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="max-width">
    <div class="box">fix to right?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't seem to do the trick... Applied this to the snippet, and it just extended the .box out of the max-width container.

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the issue at hand, since I need I for the fixed-positioned div to remain 20% of the max-width div. When I stretch the window beyond 500px max-width, the fixed div expands as well, which is not desired.

Comment: What if you add another media query for bigger than 500px? i have edited my post

Comment: Figured out a solution on my own, thanks for helping.